# How to select all LINES between parenthesises in VIM

Tags: vim, textselection

Say I have the following code

```
aaa;
bbb;
ccc void () {
    xxx;
    yyy;
}
ddd;
eee;
```

Now suppose my cursor is at yyy. I'd like to highlight all code between the parenthesis `{` and `}` **inclusive** of the complete line the brackets are on. This means the highlight will look like

**before select**

[image]

**after select**

[image]

`va}` is not a solution as that produces this

[image]

Comment: Simply `va{V` will do this.

Comment: You want to add it as an answer? My answer is too complicated. Yours is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively it should be a linewise selection. But the corresponding "text-object" forces a charwise one (so there's no difference between `va{` and `Va{`).

However, you can make a selection linewise anytime. So `va{V` achieves the desired result.

I'm not sure if any mapping is needed at all. But at least `ab` should not be touched as it normally stands for parentheses ("()-block").

```
vnoremap aB aBV
```

Now `vaB` will select {}-block linewise, while `va{` will do "normal" {}-block selection.

Answer (score 1):

```
nmap vab va{$o0
```

Breaking it down

```
vab
```

highlights within the brackets inclusive of the brackets. The cursor finishes at the end of the highlight.

```
$
```

moves the cursor to the end of the line

```
o
```

moves the cursor to the other end of the highlight block

```
0
```

moves the cursor to the start of the line